# View not found even though it exists

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a problem going from a controller to a view. I have an error which tells me that the view was not found except that it exists and that it is in the right place.

What's weird is that locally when I add .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation(); then it works.
But if I remove this part or test in production, then it doesn't work anymore.

here is the tree :

[image]

Error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Areas/BackOffice/Views/Users/Index.cshtml
/Areas/BackOffice/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml
```

Controler:

```
[Area("BackOffice")]
[Authorize(Policy = "BackOfficePolicy")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public UsersController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();

        return View(users);
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))
);

builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("BackOfficePolicy", policy =>
        policy.RequireRole("BackOffice"));
});

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/AccessDenied");
});

var app = builder.Build();

AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);

app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseExceptionHandler("/Reporting/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    new CultureInfo("fr-FR")
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("fr-BE"),
    SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{area=Reporting}/{controller=Reports}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();
```

I have the impression that this comes from the fact that I have different areas but yet the view is located where the error tells me that it is sought.

Am I missing something?
(I'm using NET.7)

EDIT:

CSproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="12.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="7.0.11" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="7.0.11">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="7.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="7.0.11" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DataAccess\DataAccess.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Utility\Utility.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
        <!-- extends watching group to include *.cshtml and *.razor files -->
        <Watch Include="**\*.cshtml;*.razor;*.js;*.css" Exclude="**\obj\**\*;bin\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationDistanceVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationHotelVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\CountryVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodCategoryVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodDishesVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodSeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodTypeVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FreightVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\SeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\technicalProductionVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfBuildingVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfHeatingVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\ParticipantOriginVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\TransportVL.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Users\Index.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\Event.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\EVT\VenuesEVT.cshtml" />
    <Content Remove="Views\Shared\_LayoutReporting.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationDistanceVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationHotelVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\CountryVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodCategoryVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodDishesVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodSeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodTypeVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FreightVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\SeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\technicalProductionVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfBuildingVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfHeatingVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\ParticipantOriginVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\TransportVL.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Users\Index.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\Event.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\EVT\VenuesEVT.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\EVT\_LiveEVTCO2Result.cshtml" />
    <Watch Remove="Views\Shared\_LayoutReporting.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationDistanceVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodCategoryVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodDishesVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\AccomodationHotelVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodSeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FoodTypeVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\SeasonVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\CountryVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\FreightVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\ParticipantOriginVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TechnicalProductionVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TransportVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfBuildingVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Home\EVT\TypeOfHeatingVL.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\BackOffice\Views\Users\Index.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\Reporting\Views\Reports\EVT\VenuesEVT.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Areas\Reporting\Views\Result\Event.cshtml" />
    <None Include="Views\Shared\_LayoutReporting.cshtml" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Could you please share more relating code and how you test in production? Fundamentally we need to confirm if there is something wrong with the route, though runtimecompilation can solve in some cases.

Comment: @Ronaldoz Yes offcourse, could you tell me which code do you want to see? About production, I just upload the application on a .NET server on a FTP.

Comment: It will be better if you can share the project without sensitive information or some unnecessary functions.

Comment: @Korpin is it possible to show your .csproj file as well?

Comment: @Ronaldoz It's difficult to do because it occurs only on the backoffice part where you need an access + the right role.

Comment: @Arpit Done. I don't get whats the part at the bottom with all views.

Comment: @Korpin did you try to reproduce the error by removing the None tags? None means the files are not included during publish, that could be causing the issue, but I suppose that your IDE should automatically take care of this.

Comment: @Arpit When I comment None, Watch and Remove then it works! Thanks for  your help! Do you know why it happend?

Comment: @korpin That's great!. The None tags would instruct MSBuild to not include those files in either build or publish, which iis why the files are missing from the final output. That is what I think is happening. I am not an expert with MSBuild but I think that was the reason for the issue.I'll put it as an answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<None>` tags at the end of `.csproj` file would instruct MSBuild to not include those files in either build or publish, that could be the possible reason of missing `Index.cshtml` View.