# NetCore 6/7/8 MVC publish to AWS Windows 2022 Server IIS error

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ec2

Recently, we upgrade our old .net framework project to .net core mvc. When we are trying to deploy .net core mvc project to AWS EC2 Windows 2022 Server IIS,

> This page isn’t working
> compute-1.amazonaws.com is currently unable
> to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

1. we installed .net core 6/7/8 hosting bundle
   [image]
2. we created application pool in IIS
   [image]
3. we created site using application pool

Are there anything we are missing?

BTW, we tried to deploy .net core web api, .net core web api work fine under the same configuration and env. The MVC projects don't work.

The problem maybe the Razor page, when we created .net core 6/7/8 mvc project under visual studio 202 enterprise, we the following error,

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
> following locations were searched: /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml

We fixed this error by installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeComilation from Nuget, and add `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

Is there anyone encountered the same error and provide a solution on this issue?

Comment: Could you kindly check your `.csproj` file ? It  seems you don't include the some of view page when you deploy it.

Comment: [Here is the similiar issue,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302312/view-not-found-even-though-it-exists) you can check it first. If not helps, please let me know.

Comment: There's not a lot of information in this question, only that you migrated a .NET Framework project to a completely different platform, ASP.NET Core. There's no explanation how the migration was performed, or how the site was tested before deployment to production. Have you tried deploying to a test IIS server locally? The last paragraph about adding `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()` suggests the migration was incomplete

Comment: Try creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC project to see what files are used, what code is created and how it runs. This will help find out what's missing from the current project.